# New page opening seamlessly as a popup with different URL on apple.com. How did they do it?

Tags: popup

I was trying to replicate the effect I saw on apple.com but with no success.
On https://www.apple.com/uk/apple-watch-series-3/ if you click on learn more button (middle of the page - sports watch section) you get something like a popup, but it is not a classic popup - more something like a new page which hides complete html structure of the main page. When you click on close, URL changes and gets you back on the main page.

How did they do it? Where should I start searching?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They are making use of the Use the HTML5 History API, [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) will show you how you can accompish the same effect.